# hibernate Query to find record based on substring

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to make a Hibernate query to check if a string contains a substring.

Suppose a user class having id,name,info.

info is String which contain multiple substrings.

For example info contains strings like "hi I am from Pune".
I want to read all record which contain Pune as substring.
I tried using like query but not working.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("content",contentStringToLook));
users = (List<Post>)criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the restriction as follows:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("content","%"+contentStringToLook+"%"));
```

Comment: It is fetching all record. even the string which does not having contentStringToLook as substring i want strictly those record only which contain contentStringToLook as substring rest of the other should be ignored

Comment: %Pune will return you records that have the string ending with Pune.Pune% will return records that have the string starting with Pune.  %Pune% will return a record that have the string containing Pune in any position within it.

Comment: Check on your string that you are using in the restriction and verify it with the string returned in the records.

Comment: but it return all record which does not contain string which i want to look.for ex if there are 30 record in table out of which 10 contain pune.so it has to return me only 10 row but it is returning 30 row.but it shows that 10 row first then other

Comment: Try looking at the generated query by turning on show_sql property in hibernate configuration. Are there any other restrictions that could possibly bring in those other records?

Comment: there is no other restrictions?

Comment: Can you post the hibernate generated query, the restriction values  and the results returned that you feel aren't matching

Comment: Also what is the column datatype on which you are running like restrictions

Comment: it works. thanks there is mistake at my side only.thanks for your Answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("content",contentStringToLook, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
```

There's also MatchMode.START, .END, and .EXACT.